# How to expose a web application via ingress in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I'd like to expose some web services to be accessed from an external client in Kubernetes, many people recommended to use ingress. I've deployed an ingress controller following the guide: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/deploy/index.md.

I don't understand what's the next step to do, could anyone help explain the step with an example?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an Ingress resource and Service tied to that Ingress. For example for nginx ingress controller:

```
cat <<EOF
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
  name: foo-boo
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: foo.domain
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: http-svc
          servicePort: 80
        path: /mypath
EOF | kubectl apply -f -
```

Then you can will able to see the ingress:

```
$ kubectl get ingress foo-boo
NAME      HOSTS         ADDRESS                PORTS   AGE
foo-boo   foo.domain    someloadbalancer.com   80      6d11h
```

Then you can test it with something like `curl`:

```
$ curl -H 'Host: foo.domain' http://someloadbalancer.com/mypath
```

More about a Kubernetes Ingress [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/).

Comment: how to access from browser, "foo.domain/mypath" will work ?

Comment: You have to add an entry on the `/etc/hosts` file, if it's not a valid DNS.

Comment: @Rico, from where `someloadbalancer.com` came? How to do that in minikube?

Comment: That's if you are using AWS or a cloud provider. with minikube you'd get an IP address I believe